# How to use Auth component of Cakephp 3 in Event

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I'm using CakePHP 3.2 and proffer plugin for image uploading.

I want to rewrite the default path of proffer plugin to upload image and change image name before save.

As per the documentation of proffer from [github](https://github.com/davidyell/CakePHP3-Proffer/blob/master/docs/examples/UploadFilenameListener.md). I have created an event in `/src/Event`

Now I want to rename the file like

```
$this->Auth->user('id').'-'.$row('id').date('dmyhis').ext
```

this is what I have done

```
$newFilename = $this->Auth->user('id').'-'.$event->subject()->get('id') . '_' . Inflector::slug($event->subject()->get('name')) . date('ymdhis') . $ext;
```

But this is giving error that `Auth` can not be used here. Is there any way to use `Auth Component` outside controller ?

Comment: You don't need Auth component, but Session data.  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With cake 3.x and after, you should using this:

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth');
```

When debug it

```
debug( $this->request->session()->read('Auth') );

[
    'id' => (int) 2,
    'username' => 'admin',
    'nice_name' => 'Tommy Do',
    'first_name' => 'Huy',
    'last_name' => 'Đỗ',

    ...//and more info in UserTable
]
```

And access to each element.

```
$this->request->session()->read('Auth.nice_name');
```

Print:

```
Tommy Do
```

Hope it will help you :D

Answer (score 1):

You can access the logged in user id by loading the session.

```
use Cake\Network\Session;
$session  = new Session();
$userData = $session->read('Auth.User.id');
```

Use this as a reference: [Reading & Writing Session Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data)